# How do I add the CoreLocation framework using Xcode 10 and not swift?

Tags: xcode, core-location

I am trying to add CoreLocation to my app.

I have #import  included

Using "Framework version" A under Packaging section in the Build Settings.  I tried adding framework B under "Other Libriarian Flags" (linking section) by entering ${BUILT_Products_dir}/B.framework/B  per suggestions under another thread.

I keep getting the following error on build

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLLocationManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is there other linking of this framework that needs to be done and where?

Comment: You want to be able to use `CoreLocation` in your app but don't want to use Swift to import it?

Comment: What I mean is that I am using objective-c not swift.

Comment: You can import iOS frameworks, like `CoreLocation`, in Ob-C like how it's done in Swift. Ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511350/implementing-iphone-location-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you.  I was following some bad advice to manually include the CoreLocation framework into the project.  I remove that and used the Build phase on the app target link binbary to libraries.  Its working fine now.